# Technical issues with share and like buttons on page

Tags: php, facebook-like, share

I created my own webpage and also created a fanpage on Facebook. On my webpage, I have added a Like button addressed to fanpage and everything works fine. Also, I made a share button and like button under people posts.

Here is the problem: When someone likes any post, it works fine but they first need to confirm this like and later he can post it on his wall but this function doesn't work... I'm using this code for like button:

```
        <div class="fb">    
        <fb:share-button href="'.$rewrite->img("#ID#", "#REWRITE-TITLE#").' " type="button_count"></fb:share-button>
        </div>
```

Another problem is with the share: Everything is fine when someone wants to post image on his wall but when I am logged as a fangpage, this does not work. Im use this code for the share button:

```
        <div class="fb">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$rewrite->img("#ID#", "#REWRITE-TITLE#").'" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        </div>
```

My webpage is http://www.najslodsze.pl and my Facebook fanpage is http://www.facebook.com/Najslodszepl